# Using CTRL-O in vim help files breaks with jumping to previous file

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim 8.0, and when I browse the vim help files using CTRL-] to jump around, I find that trying to go back through the jumplist using CTRL-O works fine when the Old positions are in the current file, but things break as soon as I try to CTRL-O to an old position in a previous file. Somehow this gets treated as a jump itself, and instead of going back in the jumplist, a whole new entry is added to the jumplist instead.

The following is an example to illustrate. Suppose I was jumping around in motion.txt.gz, and then followed a link to map.txt.gz using CTRL-] and jumped around in that file. Then my jump list might look like this:

```
:jump
 jump line  col file/text
   9     1    0 help.txt
   8     1    0 motion.txt.gz
   7   313   19 motion.txt.gz
   6    75    6 motion.txt.gz
   5    87    6 motion.txt.gz
   4    96   64 motion.txt.gz
   3     1    0 *map.txt*       For Vim version 8.0.  Last change: 2017 Mar 10
   2    56   23 :lm[ap]^I{lhs} {rhs}^I^I|mapmode-l|^I^I*:lm* *:lmap*
   1   361   12 *omap-info*
>
```

Great! So far so good. But now I want to use CTRL-O to navigate back through the jump list, one-by-one, say all the way back to #7 above (line 313 col 19 in motion.txt.gz). I find that CTRL-O will work fine all the way to #3 above, like so:

```
:jump
 jump line  col file/text
   6     1    0 help.txt
   5     1    0 motion.txt.gz
   4   313   19 motion.txt.gz
   3    75    6 motion.txt.gz
   2    87    6 motion.txt.gz
   1    96   64 motion.txt.gz
>  0     1    0 *map.txt*       For Vim version 8.0.  Last change: 2017 Mar 10
   1    56   23 :lm[ap]^I{lhs} {rhs}^I^I|mapmode-l|^I^I*:lm* *:lmap*
   2   361    7 *omap-info*
```

But then the next CTRL-O does something I did not expect. Instead of moving me up one more position in the jump list, vim mysteriously treats my action as a jump from the beginning of motion.txt to line 96 col 64 of motion.txt, thus adding the beginning of motion.txt to the end of the jump list (and, by rules of the vim jump list, removing its duplicate from the list):

```
:jump
 jump line  col file/text
   9     1    0 help.txt
   8   313   19 character |linewise|.
   7    75    6 *exclusive* *inclusive*
   6    87    6 *exclusive-linewise*
   5    96   64 motion isn't yet), a special set of mappings can be used.  See |:omap|.
   4     1    0 map.txt.gz
   3    56   23 map.txt.gz
   2   361    7 map.txt.gz
   1     1    0 *motion.txt*    For Vim version 8.0.  Last change: 2017 Mar 12
>
```

While the end result is that I am indeed at line 96 col 64 of motion.txt (not shown by the >), the problem is that my jump history is now fudged. In fact the problem repeats itself with continued use of CTRL-O from #1 above to #2 above (the top of map.txt is added and I end up at line 361 col 7 of map.txt). Basically, I am unable to navigate back to line 313 col 19 of motion.txt as I had originally wanted to.

Would really love to understand what is causing this behavior. I think I've been encountering this problem repeatedly in vim for years and just never looked into it. I hope to finally find an answer. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should use `:help ctrl-t` instead of `:help ctrl-o`. You want to jump through the tag list, not the jump list.

Comment: Hmm, ok, but I still don't understand why CTRL-O is doing what it's doing in this situation. Also, the Vim help files say that either CTRL-T or CTRL-O can be used. This is in help.txt line 13: "Jump back:  Type CTRL-T or CTRL-O.  Repeat to go further back."